# Julia assignment to Nullable Node

Tags: types, julia, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign a value to a Nullable Node. To make the code more readable, I wrote a getter function. Upon using the getter function to assign a value to a node, it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Here is the code:

```
type Node
    data
    left::Nullable{Node}
    right::Nullable{Node}

    Node() = (x = new(); x.left = Nullable{Node}(); x.right = Nullable{Node}(); x)
    Node(data) = (x = new(); x.data = data; x.left = Nullable{Node}(); x.right = Nullable{Node}(); x)
end

# Helper function to return the left node
getLeft(n::Node) = n.left

n = Node(1)
# This is what I would like to have, however it returns
# "getLeft":
getLeft(n) = Node(-1)

# what works is to write:
n.left = Node(-1)
```

Of course I also tried to write:

```
function getLeft(n::TreeNode)
    return n.left
end
```

which does not make any difference.

I don't understand why the "getLeft" function does not allow assignment, even though it return "n.left", and direct assignment to "n.left" works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `getLeft(n) = Node(-1)`creates a new function that can be compiled for any type other than Node (because you wrote a more specific function for the type node : `getLeft(n::Node) = n.left`
That's why you should see `getLeft (generic function with 2 methods)` if you type your code in the REPL

You might be tempted to write

> left = getLeft(n)
>   left = Node(-1)

But that wouldn't work either, the first line creates an alias, `left`, for the object pointed to by `n.left`
Then the second line creates a Node and reassigns the alias `left` to that node, neither `n` or `n.left` are modified

What you could do is write a function to assign a left node e.g.

> function setLeft!(n, l)
>       n.left = l
>   end
>
> > setLeft!(n, Node(-1))

But you might prefer to stick with assigning n.left directly

Comment: Thats it. Your spot on. Of course it also makes perfect sense as Node(1) is just a function. So I assigned a function Node() to a function getLeft(). So the moral of the story is that the assignment is being evaluated before the functions call.

Comment: I'm wondering if this issue is worth discussing as a language 'bug' though. The alias issue aside, syntactically speaking, OP's expectation that `getLeft(n)` should have been evaluated first is not unreasonable. Perhaps there should be a requirement for already-defined actions to explicitly state the `::Any` type in such situations, to disambiguate between an evaluation and a new function definition.

Comment: Actually, no, nevermind, I managed to confuse myself. `=` in julia is always label assignment and never an 'assignment constructor', so that syntax wouldn't make any sense in any scenario. my bad.